# Trying to make drop down menu touch-friendly, problems with finding target

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, target

So I'm trying to make a drop-down menu touch-friendly but it doesn't work. You can see it live at [this](http://bok-it.underbakke.net) website.

Here's the code:

```
$('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
$('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);
$('.myMenu > li').bind('click', openSubMenu);
$('body, .container, .topcont, header').bind('click', closeSubMenu);
$currentopen = "";
function openSubMenu() {
    $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(this).find('ul').css('opacity', '1'); 
    $currentopen = $(this).attr("id");
};

function closeSubMenu() {
    $("#" + $currentopen).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden');   
    $("#" + $currentopen).find('ul').css('opacity', '0');   
};
```

Comment: I would recommend you to include your html file as well as making a new jsfiddle so it would help troubleshooting for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that tablets and stuff already automatically do this.

Best is to download the jQuery flexnav plugin: http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/